# Google Cloud Print – Job Queuing Mechanism Internals

Tags: google-cloud-print

I have a server application that manages and prints to several GCP printers. This has been working as designed for several months until this morning. The symptomology is as follows:

- Job queue for printer is empty. There are no outstanding jobs.
- A new job shows up in the job queue at
  http://www.google.com/cloudprint as expected.
- The job status does not change from “Queued” to “In Process” or
  “Printed” for several minutes at a time. Over 30 minutes is as long
  as I have waited so far.
- If I send a follow-up job to the same printer, the first job almost
  immediately prints and the new job is queued with the delaying
  behavior described above.

The code I have that is sending data to GCP is clearly working as I expect. GCP recognizes all the jobs I submit.

GCP can clearly (but possibly only intermittently, however statistically improbable a coincidence that would be) see the printers it sends jobs.

It seems the issue causing the behavior I have seen must be in the GCP cloud itself. The problem is almost certainly in the GCP queuing and retry processing. So, what I would like to know includes:

1. Has anyone ever seen this behavior before?
2. Does anyone know of a way to see performance metrics inside the GCP
   cloud or newsfeeds that might document GCP system status?
3. Does anyone know the specifics behind the GCP queuing and retry
   mechanism?
4. Does anyone have suggestions on what might be causing this other
   than GCP internals?
5. Does anyone have any contact information for the GCP team? (I’ve
   gone so far as to call their front desk and try to sweet talk the
   receptionist to get me access. All I can get it the very limited,
   read-only help page.)

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience several months ago and I believe that it is/was a problem on GCP server side.  We were unable to correct the problem on the client side (removing/adding printers, changing clients, etc.)  The only option was to complain to Google (good luck) and wait for them to fix it.